# Type Mismatch error when entering CIM_DATETIME in wbemtest

Tags: wmi, wbem

I'm trying to execute a WMI method using wbemtest.exe.  I've selected the method in the select box, clicked the "Edit In Parameters", and I'm presented with "Object editor for __PARAMETERS".  From there I select the parameter with type "CIM_DATETIME", and click "Edit Property" to be presented with the "Property Editor" window.  From there, I'm selecting "Not NULL" and entering a value in the format described on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Here's an example:

```
2013-05-10 15:45:38:000
```

When I click "Save Property", I get the following error:

```
Number: 0x80041005
Facility: WMI
Description: Type mismatch
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CIM_DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387237.aspx) article you linked to describes two WMI date and time formats. You need to use the other one:

```
yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU
```

For example:

```
20130510154538.000000+000
```